# Can chrome extension background pages have multiple listeners?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

I'm building a chrome extension and trying to get data from twitter and then pass that to my contentscript. I'm having a lot of problems with this. I'm able to get the data from the remote site but can't seem to pass it to my content script. I have a listener for when i click the icon using `chrome.extension.onclick.addlistener(functionname);`. This gets the data. The Problem is once i get the data, i need to send a response to the request from my content script. So i'm also calling `chrome.extension.Onrequest.addlistener(functioname);`. Before i go on trying to figure out what's wrong with the code, is it allowed to have 2 listeners for 2 separate events in the same page as i've done or can you only have one listener?

Comment: I imagine you could test this out yourself in about the same amount of time it took you to ask your question.

Comment: I tested and i'm unable to tell if my code has a problem or if the code is fine and it is down to this rule. If you have a more useful response i would appreciate it.

Comment: Would you mind to share some code? That way other people can look for possible problems in your code.

Comment: To answer the title (which is how I arrived that this page) - A Chrome Extension CAN have multiple listeners in its background pages.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a crazy old question, but I came across this while experiencing a related issue and wanted to share in case it was useful for anyone else.

Make sure you're only calling the `sendResponse` method at most once if you do have multiple listeners. From the docs:

> sendResponse: Function to call (at most once) when you have a response.
>   The argument should be any JSON-ifiable object. If you have more than
>   one onMessage listener in the same document, then only one may send a
>   response. This function becomes invalid when the event listener
>   returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate
>   you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message
>   channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

Answer (score 0):

If you do a quick search on Stackoverflow, you will see many examples with code on how to send messages from background page to content script:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=content%20script%20background%20page

For more information how to do this, you can follow the docs themselves, they have great examples:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

From the documentation (copy paste):

**content_script.cs**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.greeting == "hello")
   sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
 else
   sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

**background.html**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have created a listener for the onClick event and a listener for the onRequest event is not a problem.  You can tell by typing out chrome.onClick and chrome.OnRequest at the console for the background page; you'll see they are each instances of type 'chrome.Event'.

If you think about it, if you were only able to create one listener it would greatly reduce your ability to write something useful since you could only respond to one of { onrequest, onclick, ontabchange, onconnect, ondisconnect, etc. }